# Package titlesec Error

Tags: titlesec

I have a problem with package titlesec when i tried put chapter name and chapter number in the same line ! Please help me ! Thank you very much!

```
% !TeX encoding = windows-1251
\documentclass[%
12pt,
candidate,  
natbib,      
subf,        
%fixint,     
%classified, 
%facsimile,  
]{disser}

\usepackage[
a4paper, mag=1000,
left=3cm, right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, headsep=0.7cm, footskip=1cm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=red,
    filecolor=yellow,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\ifpdf\usepackage{epstopdf}\fi

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{diagbox}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage {tikz}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{plaintop}

\restylefloat{table}

\usepackage{titlesec}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Математическое моделирование потоковых явлений (процессов) в сетеподобных носителях}

\end{document}
```

errors here

```
Missing number, treated as zero. \tt|@extract\subsection

Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \tt|@extract\subsection

Missing number, treated as zero. \tt|@extract\subsection
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \tt|@extract\subsubsection

Missing number, treated as zero. \tt|@extract\paragraph

Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \tt|@extract\paragraph

Missing number, treated as zero. \tt|@extract\ubparagraph

Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \tt|@extract\subparagraph

Missing number, treated as zero.

Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

Unknown document class (or package),(caption) standard defaults will be used."
```

Comment: your class is not compatible with titlesec.

Comment: More precisely, the class redefines `\@startsection`. It is designed to be used “as is”.